# setInterval weird behavior

Tags: javascript, express, setinterval, server-sent-events

while exploring the SSE I found that something happens weird in my project.My aim is to send some data to the browser within some time interval so I decided to use the `setInterval` function but I passed the `res.write` directly as a callback instead of enclosing it in an anonymous function.Here is where I pave the way to the Hell on my own.Because it didn't works as expected and didn't give any clue about that error.

This was the code i used `setInterval(res.write,3000,"data:foobar\n\n")`

The error I got back is

```
    msg._implicitHeader();
        ^

TypeError: msg._implicitHeader is not a function
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:650:9)
    at Timeout.write [as _onTimeout] (_http_outgoing.js:629:15)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:556:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

But when wrapping the code inside the anonymous function works as expected.
I think that this error is due to the properties used inside the `res.write` and `setInterval` got clashed or due to binding of params passed to `setInterval`.I am not sure about it.

Somebody give the technical details behind it.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz     ```setInterval(()=>{ res.write("data:chella\n\n");},1000)``` it works pretty well with arrow and normal js function.

Comment: setInterval alters calling scope `setInterval(res.write.bind(res,"data:foobar\n\n"), 3000)`

Comment: @epascarello  it means that the value of `this` inside the res.write get's altered right?

Comment: yes............

Comment: @epascarello  could you provide a docs or any examples that proves your answer?

Comment: Um, docs on MDN?

Comment: Uhh I have missed It.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#the_this_problem